# Visual Studio Mobile Center - Xamarin Forms SIGABRT - Fatal error

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio, mobile-center, visual-studio-app-center

When I try to integrate Mobile Center Analytics/Crashes, I received SIGABRT error.

I have a Xamarin.Forms project. The project works fine without Mobile Center Analytics/Crashes component but, when I use this line of code it throws the below error.

#### Code

```
MobileCenter.Start(typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
MobileCenter.Configure("{ app-secret-key }");
```

#### Error

> "Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
> a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
> used by your application."

I have followed [this link](https://docs.mobile.azure.com/sdk/Xamarin/getting-started/) to integrate Mobile Center to my Xamarin.Forms project.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, the main engineer able to help you on this topic does not have a stack overflow account with reputation to comment here and we don't have an answer yet. Since it's more a bug investigation than a simple question, can you contact us within the feedback blue intercom button on https://mobile.azure.com so that we can reply back and forth in a more convenient way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah sure...
Thanks @Guillaume Perrot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this bug by upgrading XamarinStudio, Xamarin.iOS and Xcode.
Thanks to mobile-center support...

Comment: Hi Senthamizh, when you get a chance, please mark this question as "Answered" to help future developers who may have the same question!